# Magento 1.8.0.0 payment methods template not rendering

Tags: ajax, magento

The Payment Information step of one-page checkout is empty.

I traced the ajax request all the way to OnepageController::_getPaymentMethodsHtml, the return value of which is empty.  This occurs with my custom theme and also the Magento default theme.

I have multiple payment methods enabled. The problem is that the payment/methods.phtml template is not being rendered at all.

This is a fresh Magento install, not an upgrade.

**UPDATE: Output for AW_Sarp2 was disabled in the System > Advanced settings.  This was preventing all payment methods from displaying.**

Comment: We had a similar problem, but I cannot remember how we fixed it. It was because of some conflict between prototype.js and jQuery libraries, if I remember correctly. prototype.js and jQuery use the same "$" symbol. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a javascript issue.  I verified that the controller method to get the payment methods is being called.  It's the result of trying to load the payment method block that is blank.

Comment: Found the problem.  Output for AW_Sarp2 was disabled in the System > Advanced settings.  I don't know why a recurring payments module would completely override all other payment methods, but that was the problem.